# http://localhost:52951/app/app/app.module.js 404 (Not Found) scripts in layout not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular5

Im trying to add angular 5 to my mvc project for almost two days now and its not working. When I load the page I get these errors

[image]

my scripts view is an .ascx file and the scripts look like this

```html
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<base href="/">

<script src="<%: Url.ContentWithTimestamp("~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.ContentWithTimestamp("~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.ContentWithTimestamp("~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.ContentWithTimestamp("~/systemjs.config.js") %>"></script>


<script>
    SystemJS.import('<%: Url.ContentWithTimestamp("~/app/main.js") %>').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Edit: This is the project I put angular in.

[image]

Here is one of the packages (dont want to upload img of everyone.They are there.)

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand the link between your ascx, which shows some stuff allegedly in a subfolder of "node_modules", with the screenshots of your project, which show some different files in a different folder. What are we supposed to understand from that? The errors are telling you the script files are not in the location you specified. You need to specify the correct location, that's all. We can't see your project to know where they are. Are they static source files, or the result of some typescript build process? We don't even know that for sure (although perhaps an Angular expert might).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my main.js. This line:
var app_module_1 = require("./app/app.module");
should be like this:
var app_module_1 = require("./app.module");